# Program won't show nothing on run, just the '0' value

Tags: c++, codeblocks

It should show on the screen in this order :

- even numbers on odd positions ;
- numbers with first digit equal with the last one ( for which i've done " bool cifre( int x ) " ) ;
- in the "g" file it should show the last operation i've done between maximum and minimum value of the vector .

I RUN IT AND IT JUST SHOWS " 0 " ON THE SCREEN AND NOTHING MORE . PLEASE HELP!

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <math.h>

 using namespace std;
 int n , v[101] , i , a , u , p , gasit=0 ;

 bool cifre( int x )
 {
 a = x ;
 u = x%10 ;
 while ( x!=0 )
{ 
    p = x%10 ;
    x = x/10 ;
}
if( p == u )
    return true ;
}

int main()

{
 ifstream f ( "atestat.in" ) ;
 ofstream g ( "atestat.out" ) ;
 for( i=1 ; i<=n ; i++ )
    {
      f >> v[i] ;
      if( v[i]%2 == 0 && i%2 != 0 )
        cout << v[i] ;
    }
  int min=v[n] ;
  int max=v[1] ;
  for( i=1 ; i<=n ; i++ )
    if ( cifre( v[i] ) == true )
       {
          cout << v[i] << " " ;
          gasit++ ;
        }

  if ( gasit==0 )
    cout << "NU EXISTA" ;
  cout << endl ;
  for( i=1 ; i<=n ; i++ )
    {
      if ( v[i] > max )
        max = v[i] ;
      if ( v[i] < min )
        min = v[i] ;
    }
   cout << ( max + min ) /. 2 ;
   f.close() ;
   g.close() ;
   return 0 ;
 }
```

Comment: I strongly recommend giving identifiers descriptive names. Makes for easier reading and often much easier debugging.

Comment: I don't understand how should i describe them, like " counter " instead of " i " ? Or how exactly? Give me some examples, if you have time, please :)

Comment: If the variable is used to hold a count, `counter`'s great. If it's used to index, `index`. If it contains the sum of a list of numbers, `sum`. If it is a list of numbers, 'numlist`. `min` and `max` are great. They tell me everything I need to know about what they represent. `f` and `g` tell me nothing, but `infile` and `outfile` provide great hints. Name a variable according to what it represents and a function according to what it does..

Comment: Just having a good name can help you spot bugs `infile << result;` would raise alarm bells, why is the code writing to an input file, that `f << a` cannot convey.

Comment: Wow this is nice! I really have to try this!!! I am not very good at keeping things organised and all that jazz... Soo this advice will catch me well :) Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You start a for loop to end at 'n', yet you have not gave it a value.

```
n=3; // example
for( i=1 ; i<=n ; i++ )
```

Comment: Oh god... you right ! ... i forgot they didn't give an exact value for n to be read... so i think i should do the things with "while" instead of "for" :-?

Comment: @VladGabriel For can also work, but while loop would be more efficient in reading files.